# Install Grub when ssd is hd1

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have a Dell G3 17 3779 laptop. 
It has sata HDD as hd0 and m.2 ssd as hd1. Both in GPT.

I deleted everything in the ssd and installed Windows 10. 
I used 4 partitions:

- Windows recovery environment (499M) | `/dev/sdb1`
- EFI System (100M) | `/dev/sdb2`
- Microsoft reserved (MSR) (16M) | `/dev/sdb3`
- Main Windows NTFS partition (70G) | `/dev/sdb4`

Also I added for Arch Linux 2 partitions:

- For `/` (47.7G) | `/dev/sdb5`
- For swap (980.3M) | `/dev/sdb6`

HDD disk has 2 partitions:

- Microsoft reserved (MSR) (16M) | `/dev/sda1`
- Some NTFS (900G) | `/dev/sda2`

After Windows I installed arch linux from UEFI following the wiki manual.

GRUB was installed with the usual `grub-install` without keys

I tried to configure GRUB with manual config:

*/boot/grub/grub.cfg*

```
. $prefix/menu.cfg
```

*/boot/grub/menu.cfg*

```
set default=0
set timeout=10
menuentry "ArchLinux" {
 linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sdb4 rw
 initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img
}
menuentry "Windows" {
  regexp -s root '\((.+)\)' "$cmdpath"
  chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

After rebooting just started Windows 10 without any boot menus.

I installed `os-prober` and tried `grub-mkconfig` and get some warning like: 
`WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.`  
or  
`WARNING: Device /dev/loop0 not initialized in udev database even after waiting 10000000 microseconds.`

Instead `/dev/loop0` was in all partitions.

And still booting only Windows.

May be it because my HDD is first in BIOS unlike SSD (hd0 vs hd1)?

How to fix this problem?

*update:*  this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/816347/879272 allows me to open grub.

But why BIOS started EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi ignoring another boot loaders. 
Can I disable this behavior?

[image: fdisk]

[image: EFI]

Comment: I don't see any information in this question about what you've tried changing in the BIOS.  EFI allows you to install multiple bootloaders. Usually you set the boot priority in the BIOS.

Comment: On an UEFI system, the outputs of `efibootmgr -v` and `lsblk -o +PARTUUID` would be important in troubleshooting a problem like this. The former will tell you what boot options the firmware knows about, and together with the latter, you will be able to find out exactly which disk and which `.efi` bootloader file is used by the firmware with each boot option.

Answer (score 0):

I think the BIOS is still telling the G3 to boot Windows.

The Dell BIOS has a good file browser to select the bootloader. Enter the BIOS setup (maybe F2 or F8) as soon as you see the Dell logo screen and before Windows starts. Next use the file browser to locate the bootloader grubx64.efi you want to boot and select. Then review the boot order and save the new settings to reboot to Grub.

Comment: F12, then choose Setup Bios. I saw boot menu and grubx64.efi was before than Windows Boot Manager in Boot Order

Comment: Anyway, will try something again in weekend

Comment: Now I tried again install arch and grub. After rebooting started Windows. When I open boot menu (F12) and choose arch started Support Assistent memory test

Comment: Bios boot config: https://imgur.com/a/CVSabQ4

Comment: Could you try to go into the BIOS and turn off the HDD in the SATA section leaving just the SSD to boot? If you can boot to Arch then maybe try to install another kernel and see if the pacman makes a good grubx64.efi automatically? You are very close now.

Comment: I just remembered the Dell always sets the SATA to RAID not AHCI so that would be good to check.

Comment: I see "SATA Operation" with turn on AHCI

Comment: when I disabled SATA Operation, I can't boot even WIndows. Just started support asistent memory test. Also disappeared from boot menu "UEFI Intel SSD ... Partition 2"

Comment: I think you can disable the SATA drives separately. I have setup 2 Dell laptops with UEFI just don't have them any more. Maybe the G3 is different. Sorry for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something wrong with the grubx64.efi bootloader. Here is an amazing utility that can boot anything anywhere without a bootloader:

[SuperGrub2](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/)

EDIT: As an alternate, there is the excellent '[refind](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind)' boot manager and specializing in booting the EFI. The utility can be installed to a usb removable disk for allowing an emergency boot of an otherwise unbootable fixed disk or can be installed to the EFI system partition for regular use. The 'refind' can find a grub bootloader or boot the installed kernel directly if built with the UEFI bootloader stub as is frequently included with modern linux distributions.

[refind](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)

Answer (score 0):

Several weeks ago I had the same problem on my laptop. It ignored my GRUB2 and start Windows directly. Here is how I solved this problem:

1. Rename the directory `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft` to `Microsoft0`
2. Change the path in `chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` accordingly, to `/EFI/Microsoft0/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`

It seems that the BIOS in my laptop will always put Microsoft boot loader at the top of the list, no matter how you configure it. So, renaming the `Microsoft` directory in the EFI partition can fool the BIOS and it won't boot into Windows automatically.

Comment: Seems like this:  https://askubuntu.com/a/816347/879272 :)

Answer (score 0):

TBH I do not know the root cause of a similar issue I had dual booting with Win10 and Kali but I spent ages trying to get them to dual boot and failed. This is the hack I used to get it working.

- With Win installed
- Disable secureboot in bios
- Disable fastboot in bios
- Install Ubuntu. Because Ubuntu pays nicely with Win, it installs `grub` in a way that Win 'likes' and the machine then successfully dual booted both Win and Ubuntu
- Install other linux OS (in my case Kali) but without re-installing `grub`
- Boot into Ubuntu and reconfigure `grub` from Ubuntu (I used `grubcustomizer') to a triple boot
- Uninstall Ubuntu
- Boot into your other OS and clean up `grub` and set the boot priority to boot as desired (again I used `grubcustomizer`).

When I migrated to this (new) machine I just installed Arch and run windows from Virtualbox, copied the Win data to a folder and shared the folder between the Win VM and Arch. I can now have both machines running (Arch as the workhorse and Win as VM) and work on the shared data drive from whichever platform suits any particular task.